# Refresh of Page Upon Incorrect Entry in Form Data

Tags: php, wordpress

So, this is my first question here, and I apologize for not being a very confident coder. (Not my primary position...)

We're using a Wordpress site with a little bit of additional code, using a PHP file for redirection of site movement based on form input. An example of what we use is as follows:

```
<?php //Turn the content from text box into variable
$page=$_POST['text'];

if($_POST['text']=='sit') {
//set up a redirect to that page
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"0;URL=http://exampleurl.com/index.php/private/core\">";

}

else if($_POST['text']=='pony') {
//set up a redirect to that page
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"0;URL=http://exampleurl.com/index.php/private/ponytail\">";

}
```

It's worked really well for us, but I've been asked to possibly add some code that if an individual enter an incorrect term, value, etc that it won't just cycle to a blank page but instead refresh the page that it's on.

Anything that we can add to this php file to get the desired function?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a last `else` condition like below. Adapt the `http://exampleurl.com/index.php/`to the desired page.

```
<?php //Turn the content from text box into variable
$page=$_POST['text'];

if($_POST['text']=='sit') {
   //set up a redirect to that page
   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"0;URL=http://exampleurl.com/index.php/private/core\">";

}

else if($_POST['text']=='pony') {
   //set up a redirect to that page
   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"0;URL=http://exampleurl.com/index.php/private/ponytail\">";

} else {
   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"0;URL=http://exampleurl.com/index.php/">";
}
```